# Flex: Configure AMF serialization warnings?

Tags: apache-flex, serialization, amf

I have been trying to test my application to make sure that all the important classes can serialize/reload themselves properly (especially those which implement `IExternalizable`):

```
[Test]
public function testMyObjectSerialization():void {
    var myobj:MyObject = new MyObject();
    var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    ba.writeObject(myobj);
    ba.position = 0;
    var loadedObj:MyObject = ba.readObject();
    assertMyObjectEqual(myobj, loadedObj);
}
```

And I would like to be warned when I try to serialize a strongly-typed object which does not have a `[RemoteClass]` set (because that almost certainly represents a bug in my code).

So, is there any way to configure the AMF serializer to give warnings?

Also, it seems like this *might* be possible using `services-config.xml`… But the documentation seems to imply that `services-config` is channel-level, and I'd really like it if my unit tests could run without talking to the server (and I'm not using LCDS, so a bunch of the `services-config` wouldn't apply to me anyway).

Comment: Do you want the warnings to appear at compile time or runtime?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for them to appear at compile time… For example, if I've got `class Foo { var bars:Array = [ new Bar(), new Baz() ] }`, it'd be impossible for the compiler to know A) that I want to serialize `bars` and B) that `bars` contains a `Baz`.

Comment: So, yea - I'd like them to appear at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure the native AMF serialization/deserialization from the Flash Player to give you warnings if [RemoteClass] or any other metadata is set or not.

However you can write your own class to do that - you can register all the objects in a list and check for [Remote] using flash.utils.describeType. Or use a wrapper over writeObject which check for the [Remote] metadata.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, that won't work for classes which implement `IExternalizable`, because there's no way of knowing what they will write to the output stream. Of course, I could create a subclass of `ByteArray`, which watches *everything* being written to it… But that seems like a fair amount of pain :(

Comment: Also, do you have a reference for "there is no way to configure the native AMF serialization/deserialzation"? Because it *seems* like, if I was using `services-config.xml` and an LCDS server, then it would be possible…

Comment: I do not have a public reference, I just asked an FP engineer near my desk. On the server side it is a different story..you can customize many things and the code is open source.

Comment: Ah, ok :) That's much better than I've got. Thanks.